# What does `synchronized` do when I get continuous result from the same thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to do some exercises for producers and consumers. 
Code is below, which is thread-safe, but this code does not solve the  synchronization between producers and consumers.

**code**

```
package edu.seu.juc.pac;

import edu.seu.juc.annotation.ThreadSafe;

@ThreadSafe
public class TestProducerAndConsumer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Clerk clerk = new Clerk();

        Producer producer = new Producer(clerk);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(clerk);

        new Thread(producer, "producer A").start();
        new Thread(consumer, "consumer B").start();
    }


    private static class Clerk {
        private int product = 0;

        public synchronized void get() {
            if (product >= 10) {
                System.out.println("product is full");
            } else {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " produce: " + (++product));
            }
        }

        public synchronized void sale() {
            if (product <= 0) {
                System.out.println("product is lack");
            } else {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consume: " + (--product));
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Producer implements Runnable {
        private Clerk clerk;

        public Producer(Clerk clerk) {
            this.clerk = clerk;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                clerk.get();
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Consumer implements Runnable {
        private Clerk clerk;

        public Consumer(Clerk clerk) {
            this.clerk = clerk;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                clerk.sale();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**true result**

```
producer A produce: 1
producer A produce: 2
producer A produce: 3
producer A produce: 4
producer A produce: 5
product is full
product is full
product is full
product is full
product is full
consumer B consume: 4
consumer B consume: 3
consumer B consume: 2
consumer B consume: 1
consumer B consume: 0
product is lack
product is lack
product is lack
product is lack
product is lack
```

In my opinion, the result may be like below for example,
**one of my expected results**

```
producer A produce: 1
producer A produce: 2
producer A produce: 3
producer A produce: 4
producer A produce: 5
consumer B consume: 4
consumer B consume: 3
consumer B consume: 2
consumer B consume: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
producer A produce: 2
producer A produce: 3
producer A produce: 4
producer A produce: 5
consumer B consume: 4
consumer B consume: 3
consumer B consume: 2
consumer B consume: 1
consumer B consume: 0
```

There must be something done by `volatile`. Could someone tell me the reason or keywords for searching.

Comment: Why do you think this code isn't thread-safe? What exactly do you mean by "thread-safe"?

Comment: @AndyTurner Oh. The code is thread-safe, but not a good solution to Producer–consumer problem. I fix my question.

Comment: @JosanSun *"Code is below, which is thread-safe, but this code does not solve the synchronization between producers and consumers."*, when it's thread-safe, it *doesn't* have synchronization problems.

Comment: @akuzminykh I think it is thread-safe, because it keeps the inconsistency of `product` for producer and consumer thread. In other words, the `product` is guaranteed to be free of race conditions in this code. Refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that when the "product is full", the producer should wait for the consumer to consume the product and when the "product is lack", the consumer should wait for the producer to produce the product. in this way the two threads will work "in tandem", while now they are working "sequentially".

this can be acheived *easily* using [`wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) and [`notify()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify())/[`notifyAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll()) methods.

changing the `Clerk` class using `wait()` and `notifyAll()` to implement the "waiting" leads to your expected output:

```
private static class Clerk {
        private int product = 0;

        public synchronized void get() {
                while (product >= 5) {
                        try {
                                wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                continue;
                        }
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " produce: " + (++product));
                notifyAll();
        }

        public synchronized void sale() {
                while (product <= 0) {
                        try {
                                wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                continue;
                        }
                }
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " consume: " + (--product));
                notifyAll();
        }
}
```

---

```
$ javac TestProducerAndConsumer.java
$ java TestProducerAndConsumer
producer A produce: 1
producer A produce: 2
producer A produce: 3
producer A produce: 4
producer A produce: 5
consumer B consume: 4
consumer B consume: 3
consumer B consume: 2
consumer B consume: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
producer A produce: 2
producer A produce: 3
producer A produce: 4
producer A produce: 5
consumer B consume: 4
consumer B consume: 3
consumer B consume: 2
consumer B consume: 1
consumer B consume: 0
```

**edit**:

> But for this question, I doubt for the continuous result by the same thread. It seems like working in sequence.

I think that this is due to the fact that the producer and consumer are running inside a loop and when "it's the producer turn" it re-acquires the lock on the object *before* the consumer have a chance to do so (and viceversa).

if we add a `Thread.sleep(1)` of just *1 millisecond* after each `.get()` and `.sale()` we'll see "mixed" results in the output:

```
private static class Producer implements Runnable {
        private Clerk clerk;

        public Producer(Clerk clerk) {
                this.clerk = clerk;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        clerk.get();
                        try {
                                Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        }
}

private static class Consumer implements Runnable {
        private Clerk clerk;

        public Consumer(Clerk clerk) {
                this.clerk = clerk;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        clerk.sale();
                        try {
                                Thread.sleep(1);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

---

```
$ javac TestProducerAndConsumer.java
$ java TestProducerAndConsumer
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
producer A produce: 1
consumer B consume: 0
```

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding question. I know the solution of Producer–consumer problem. But for this question, I doubt for the continuous result by the same thread. It seems like working in sequence.

Comment: @JosanSun I updated my answer trying to clarify this "sequential output" doubt.

Comment: Yeah, the root cause may be the loop. When I remove the `synchronized`, and use `volatile` to `product`. It results in almost the same result. Before, I think this  may be related to the Biased Locking in `synchronized`. Maybe, I think too more.

Comment: @JosanSun be careful, `volatile` is not a replacement for `synchronized`

Comment: I know that. I do this for my test. Because I guess something done by `synchronized` before. Then I change `synchronized` to `volatile` to test my guess. Anyway, thank you for your remind.